# RBAC динамическое назначение прав пользователям

Tags: php, yii2

Использую Yii2 c RBAC и DbManager. Возник вопрос, можно ли динамически назначать пользователям права и роли? По сути хочу админку с кучей галочек что можно делать, а что нельзя. Спасибо

Comment: А в чем сложность ? Создаете веб форму и отправляете запросы к БД в зависимости от выбранных галочек. Ответ на ваш вопрос: да. Только незабудте проверить настройки кэширования, если изменения прав и ролей критичны.

Answer (score 1):

если вы имеете ввиду назначение ролей админом пользователям - **да, можно.** делается это вызовом таблицы auth_assignment, где впоследствии меняются соответствующие поля.

а если вы имели ввиду автоматическое назначение роли пользователю после регистрации, то ответ - **да, можно.** в модели регистрации после создания и сохранения пользователя в таблице auth_assignment выставляете соответствующие полям значения.